# Unsuccessfull payment transfer using Paypal with nodejs

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am trying to implement the Paypal gateway method in nodejs. I am successful redirecting to paypal from my nodejs and when I click on pay I get "Error": "Response Status : 400", with an unsuccessful payment.

My API and its response are given below in detail.

```
    paypal.configure({
     'mode': 'sandbox', //sandbox or live
     'client_id': 'ATXsRtel_YoAQHVIwP4Z_bmX3VkL1n1N_fJ6FH2os0GynozBJo-Oler8wFVvXzoPpNwbfCAYFvCL76Ke',
     'client_secret': 'EAwUmjDRpC-fqz_Fcs262MKrdMDltXJnWiA- 
    N6gURWcJq1N9IpwzISfcCMLNHzXFJ_38YLQXG3jtUK8a'
   });
```

Post Api for req.body and get the url back

```
 Router.post('/Pay',(req,res)=>{
   const create_payment_json = {
      "intent": "sale",
      "payer": {
          "payment_method": "paypal"
      },
      "redirect_urls": {
          "return_url": "http://localhost:7070/PayPal/PaymentSuccess",
          "cancel_url": "http://localhost:7070/PayPal/PaymentCancel"
      },
      "transactions": [{
          "item_list": {
              "items": [{
                  "name": "ball",
                  "sku": "001",
                  "price": "25.00",
                  "currency": "USD",
                  "quantity": 1
              }]
          },
          "amount": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "25.00"
          },
          "description": "Testing Product"
      }]
  };

   paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
       if (error) {
          res.json({
              Message:'Un Approved',
              Error:error.message
          })
      } else {
          payment.links.map(_AllLinks=>{
              if(_AllLinks.rel === 'approval_url'){
                  res.json({
                      Message:'Approved',
                      Url:_AllLinks.href
                  })
              }
          })
      }
  });
})
```

Rout to get payerID

```
  Router.get('/PaymentSuccess',(req,res)=>{
  let payerId = req.query.PayerID;
  let paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

  console.log({
      payerId:payerId,
      paymentId:paymentId
  });
    let execute_payment_json = {
      "payer_id" : payerId,
      "transaction" : [{
          "amount":{
              "currency":"USD",
              "total":"25.00"
          }
      }]
  }

  paypal.payment.execute(paymentId,execute_payment_json, function(error,payment){
      if(error){
          res.json({
              Error:error.message,
              Message:error
          })
      }else {
          res.json({
              Result:payment
          })
      }
  })
```

})

```
 Router.get('/PaymentCancel',(req,res)=>{
    res.json({
         Result:'Cancelled'
    })
 })
```

The response i get and my payment got unsuccessful.

```
// 20210504063330
// http://localhost:7070/PayPal/PaymentSuccess?paymentId=PAYID-MCIKIRQ60G27157PA787072M&token=EC- 
9EU01414K39004833&PayerID=GFYGLAXW36YPW

{
  "Error": "Response Status : 400",
  "Message": {
    "response": {
      "name": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
      "message": "Invalid request - see details",
      "debug_id": "cfeb4eab621c7",
      "details": [
        {
          "field": "/transaction",
          "location": "body",
          "issue": "MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON"
        }
      ],
      "links": [
    
      ],
      "httpStatusCode": 400
    },
    "httpStatusCode": 400
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v1/payments REST API is deprecated. Use the current v2/checkout/orders API instead.

The best integration uses no redirects, and keeps your site loaded in the background with an in-context approval.

---

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: bro I am using angular and any snippet for this api.

Comment: That's the client side. There is a driver you can try: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/single-page-app/

Comment: bro so this client side is enough for the payment transactions or do i need to write apis for it?

Comment: A server integration is recommended, see the last link in my answer for how the client side communicates with the server.

Comment: got it bro so for client side i need to use the angular script provided by paypal and then connect it with the server which you ave provided in the link in the answer for successful transcation